# Oracle SQL: create procedure that takes a table as input

Tags: sql, oracle, function, procedure

I would like to create a procedure that takes a table (T in the example) as an input.
However I don't want to provide the table name as a char and do something 'dynamic' like

```
begin
    execute immediate ('delete from '||T||' where ...');
end;
```

because the actual task I am dealing with involves several inputs to the function and a long query to execute which has a lot of apices... the string to execute becomes really messy and difficult to debug.
I would like to have something simple as the following (which works):

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE fun (x NUMBER) AS
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.var= fun.x;
   END;
/
```

However giving the table as an input to the procedure (I need to do it because otherwise, in the real task, I would need to change the "T" in a lot of occurrences within the procedure)  does not work:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE fun (x NUMBER, T table) AS
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM T WHERE T.var= fun.x;
   END;
/

Errors for PROCEDURE FUN
----------------------------
L:1 C:32       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following:
                  in out <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
                  ... long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary
                  national character nchar
               The symbol "<an identifier> was inserted before "TABLE" to continue.
1 statement failed.
```

Is it possible to have something close to what I want?

Comment: If you want to pass the table name as a variable, then you need `execute immediate`.

Comment: you mean like in the first block of code I posted, which is the way I do not want to follow? There is no other way?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Thank you. I still find it incredibly strange (coming from scientific analysis softwares) that one has to go through such a mess... it's really a deal breaker.

Comment: Giuseppe, PL/SQL code is checked and compiled upon creation of the procedure/function. So, if you put a SQL statement, without using 'execute immediate ...' then it will be checked and if the table does not exist, you'll get an error. PL/SQL is a strongly-type language. Execute immediate was added to allow more dynamic code.

Answer (score 0):

I have devised a tornaround which is surely not elegant but, according to the comments, appears to be the only way to avoid large pieces of dynamic "execute immediate" code.

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE fun (T_in char, T_out char, x number) 
as
   BEGIN

    /* I create a temporary replica with a view */
   execute immediate 'create or replace view tempview as select * from '||T_in;

    /* DO STUFF, for example: */
   delete from tempview where ente_segn = fun.x;

    /* Save the results in a new table */
   execute immediate 'create or replace view '||T_out||'  as select * from tempview';

   END;
/
```